# How mongo db replicaset works in Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-rm-template, mongodb-replica-set

I have deployed the Mongo DB replica set using this template [mongodb-replica-set-centos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mongodb-replica-set-centos).

**Mongo DB VM 1 (primary):**

ps aux | grep mongo

```
root      10161  0.7  0.5 797140 40900 ?        SLl  05:18   0:05 mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --replSet repset --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf
sshuser   10347  0.0  0.0 112640   960 pts/0    S+   05:29   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

Mongo DB database:-

```
 mongo -u mongoadmin -p mongoadmin admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: admin
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-03-23T05:18:21.137+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-03-23T05:18:21.137+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
repset:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "repset",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:38:45.694Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "52.170.83.3:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 8426,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1521782318, 3),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1521782318, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.0.1.5:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 8407,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1521782318, 3),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:38:45.538Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:38:42.546Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
            "configVersion" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Mongo DB VM 2 (secondary):**

ps aux | grep mongo

```
root      10115  0.4  0.5 447908 37892 ?        SLl  05:11   0:17 mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet repset --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
sshuser   10269  0.0  0.0 112640   960 pts/0    S+   06:21   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

Mongo DB database:-

```
mongo -u mongoadmin -p mongoadmin admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: admin
2018-03-23T07:38:54.311+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1441:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

**Mongo DB VM 3(secondary):-**

ps aux | grep mongo

```
root      10122  0.6  0.5 795472 40420 ?        SLl  05:12   0:26 mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo/ --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet repset --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
sshuser   10381  0.0  0.0 112640   960 pts/0    S+   06:21   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

Mongo DB database:-

```
 mongo -u mongoadmin -p mongoadmin admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: admin
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-03-23T05:12:19.613+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2018-03-23T05:12:19.613+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
repset:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "repset",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:39:04.009Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "52.170.83.3:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 8425,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1521782318, 3),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:39:02.571Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-03-23T07:39:03.573Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1521782318, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "configVersion" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.0.1.5:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 8806,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1521782318, 3),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-03-23T05:18:38Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Questions:-

1. Why I am unable to login into Mongo DB VM 2?
2. After I shutdown Mongo DB VM 3, will Mongo DB VM 2 acts as a secondary node?
3. If I shutdown Mongo DB VM 1, Will any one of secondary node act as a primary node?

Comment: Did you tried anything by yourself to get answers to questions?

Comment: I did shutdown Mongo DB VM 3, I don't see Mongo DB VM 2 acts as a secondary node

Comment: I don’t see third node in replica set. There are only two modes so not enough members for election.

Comment: There are 3 Mongo VM. one is primary and other 2 nodes are secondary.

Comment: I see this error "Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)" in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log after I shutdown one secondary node

Comment: @Saleem Did you know how to solve this error "Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1"

Answer (score 0):

All three questions are answered by the same fact: **DB VM2 is not part of the replica set**. It's clear from the rs.status() information that only two nodes are registered as part of the replica set, VM1 and VM3.

The implications are that:

1. On DB VM2, it is not part of the replica set so it does not have the authentication credentials you are trying to log in with
2. No, DB VM2 will not act as a secondary node; because it is not part of the replica set
3. In the current setup, with only 2 nodes in the replica set, if you shut down either node (VM1 or VM3) then the other node **will not elect itself primary, because it cannot command a majority in an election**.

Take a look at the [docs on Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) to understand what the majority is and why it matters; and take a look at DB VM2 to understand why it is not part of your replica set. Did you ever actually add it?